# What is the right meaning of this sentence? ( I have ever made this.)

Tags: grammar

In our country, we learned that present perfect means past experience at school.
But I saw native speaker say that right meaning of present perfect is unspecified past. 
When we saw the sentence like:

> I have ever made this.

how can I  accept the meaning of the sentence?
'I have the experience of making this.' or 'I made this but I don't know the exact time'?

Comment: *I have ever made this* is not a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: What is the reason why this sentence is not correct sentence grammatically?

Comment: I have no idea. But you **hear** native speakers say something; you cannot see it.

Comment: If so, how about ' I have made this'?

Comment: To the OP: Had you perhaps see this in writing somewhere? To @user178049: Perhaps that's why he says he had "seen" this somewhere?

Comment: Why do you think that the two definitions are mutually exclusive? Why couldn't the present perfect be both for past experiences and the unspecified past? For example, using your own example, "I have made this before," you would be correct in saying that the speaker both has "had the experience of making this" and is speaking about the "unspecified past." (Cont'd.)

Comment: (Cont'd.) I'm not saying that any of this is correct or incorrect. Just trying to understand why you think the two ideas are at odds.

Comment: And in case more explicitness is needed, your sentence should be, "I have made this before." As Cantalouping says, "I have ever made this" is not a grammatically-correct sentence.

Comment: The "unspecified past" is merely one way of *describing* the conditions under which the present perfect is used.   The present perfect is used to refer to something which happened in the past *in terms of its relationship to the speaker's Present*.  When you say *I have done it*, you are referring to yourself now as one who is the doer of the deed, for example, an *accomplishment*.  If you understand the idea of **accomplishment**, you will understand why someone might use the present perfect to refer to a past deed.

Comment: @ Cantalouping Unlike you, I don't think that the sentence is not grammatically correct, but just semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ungrammatical because of the presence of "ever". "Ever" belongs to a group of words called "negative polarity items".

The unusual thing about negative polarity items is that they can only appear when there is some suggestion of doubt or unreality in the sentence.

Here are a few of the situations where you can use "ever":

1. In an explicitly negative sentence. Note that "ever" becomes "never" when negated.

> I have **never** done that.

2. In an implicitly negative sentence, such as one expressing doubt or infrequency.

> I hardly **ever** do that.
>
> I doubt that I've **ever** done that.

3. In a question (because the answer could be "no"!).

> Have you **ever** done that?

4. In a hypothetical situation.

> If you **ever** do this, let me know.

There are a couple of other situations. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73724) on English Language & Usage for more detail.

Another negative polarity item that often causes difficulty is "any".